# Complete case insensitiveness in R

Tags: r, case-insensitive, lowercase

i've read posts and read some more. i just want to disable case sensitivity everywhere in r. i feel like half of my key strokes is the dashing of my little finger for the shift button. i want to write `NULL` as `null` and `NA` as `na`. everything in lower case.

Comment: good luck; this is probably impossible without **serious** hacking.

Comment: It'll also wreak havoc with things like `ecdf` in base R and `Ecdf` in Frank Harrell's packages, `lag` in base R and `Lag` in xts  ...

Comment: You might, though, want to look into remapping Shift's functionality to some key that's more comfortably reachable. (I use my CapsLock key for Shift'ing, and Shift+CapsLock for CapsLock'ing.) Also make sure you're taking full advantage of tab-completion, whenever possible.

Comment: How about ya just learn to type?  I can't imagine telling your boss you don't want to put any capital letters in your memos!

Comment: Thanks Josh, I hadn't thought about Tab completion. @CARL, I can type fast. But in R more than in memos, my little fingers are swelling because I am given many variables in full higher case

Comment: Josh already mentioned tab completion, but if you're not using R studio already it has nice tab auto complete for both functions and objects in your workspace.

Comment: Following up on Josh's advice to use tab-completion, I use [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) with [Enhanced-R](https://github.com/randy3k/Enhanced-R) and it works wonders

Comment: Why couldn't he just create a variable `null <- NULL` and `na <- NA` at the beginning of his script to do this throughout? He just doesn't want to type the capitalization right?

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen, I wonder if there are situations where that would break, but it's worth a try ... (`is.na` is already lowercase, go figure ...)

Comment: Along the same lines as Dirk's query, when you type `"c"`, should it mean `c` or `C`? Should `"t"` mean `t` or `T`? Even if you could progam this, it just wouldn't work.

Comment: I don't know if this is a real problem, if you just move them to a variable. NULL and NA are values not functions. "renaming" them by assignment shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen -- I think  NULL and NA are just examples chosen to illustrate the OP's bigger question, which stems from the fact that "[he/she] just want[s] to disable case sensitivity everywhere in R".

Comment: @JoshO'Brien ah, got it. I didn't read those as examples, I read them as what he wants to change.

Comment: I tried writing a function of a function that returned a function that was the same as the argument function but with lower-case argument names. However, it fails when any argument default references another argument. EG foo=function(X=1,y=2*X){} because you have to change the RHS of the arg list too. At that point I decided it's easier for the OP to type caps than for the rest of the world to fix the OP's problem.